# Intel 8265 Bluetooth finds unavailable devices

Tags: drivers, sound, bluetooth, intel, thinkpad

I'm facing a pretty annoying bluetooth problem on my Yoga 370 with Intel 8265 Wifi/Bluetooth card. Whenever I switch on Bluetooth in Gnome settings, it tells me that my speaker (UE Boom 2) is available, even if it is switched off. It seems that my speaker is stored in some kind of cache and shows up no matter if it is switched on or not.

I tried to delete it via

```
bluetoothctl 
[bluetooth]# remove [mac address]
```

But even then, the speaker showed up as a new device

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
[NEW] Device C0:28:8D:45:C5:CC UE BOOM 2
```

I also tried to reinstall the driver of my bluetooth card via [this](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html?_ga=2.160393205.998031881.1518378570-532649952.1518378558) link, but it didn't change anything.

I also tried to connect to the speaker (while it was switched on of course) via

```
bluetoothctl 
[bluetooth]# pair [mac address]
```

But this resulted in

```
[bluetooth]# Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled
```

Is there some way to reset all bluetooth connections and start from scratch? What else could I uninstall/reset?

My system information:

- Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga 370
- Intel 8265 Wifi/Bluetooth Card
- Kernel 4.13.0-32-generic
- Ubuntu 17.10

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have the same notebook with same config and had the same problem with Debian Stretch.

The location is /var/lib/bluetooth/

There is a folder XX:YY:Z1.... (MAC of your build-in bluetooth device).

In this folder (XX:YY:Z1....) are other folders with the naming shema XX:YY:Z2.... (already configured bluetooth devices) and also a folder named cache, which contains files with the naming shema XX:YY:Z3....  (already found bluetooth devices).

You should look in the cache folder and delete all files there. Then they will not appear as already found.

If you want to delete a already configured device delete the XX:YY:Z2.... folders in the "main" folder of your build-in bluetooth device.

to be able to invoke

```
sudo -i
```

to get root access and delete files with

```
rm file_name
```

or folders with

```
rm folder_name -rf
```

Hope this helps.

I also have the

```
[bluetooth]# Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled
```

Error while trying to pair a Microsoft 3600 mouse.

If someone finds a way to solve it or knows what this error message means please let us now :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I deleted the cache and the settings folder for my bluetooth speaker, at least it doesn't show up any more when it's switched off. I cannot report back on the connection issue since I currently don't have the speaker with me, but I'll report back as soon as possible.